# In VBA, how can I store an entire excel table into an easily accessible array that contains all the relevant child information?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large excel table that contains these elements:

```
Name    Date    StartWorkedAt   FinishWorkAt    HoursWorked
```

I am creating a button to manipulate this data, but am having trouble deciding what format to store all the data in. Each person in the list will have multiple dates that they all worked, and so I would like to be able to check the start and finish times for each person for various dates.

I wrote a short script to count how many unique names I have so that I could use a multidimensional array to access the data of each person like so:

```
workTable[0][0]
```

So this would *ideally* give me the start and/or finish time of the first person on the first date that he/she worked on.

but the issue I was having was that the data is in various formats. The name is a string, the date is a Date, and the hoursWorked is an integer.

What is an easier way to store the data in VBA so that I can access each person individually and find out what date they worked and when they started and finished?

Comment: Are StartWorkedAt and FinishWorkAt in time format like 10:22:15 AM or 21:10:15 or along with date such as 27-05-2016 10;37:15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Class module` with properties for each of the columns you need and create a Collection of that class.

For example, create a class module (named say ExcelRow) with the following properties:

```
Private pName As String
Private pDate As Date
Private pStartWorkedAt As Date
Private FinishWorkAt As Date
Private HoursWorked As Integer
```

You'll need public properties for EACH of these private variables. Here's an example of setting up Get and Let for the pName property. The public vars can be differently named to the private vars:

```
Public Property Get Name() As String 
    Name = pName 
End Property 
Public Property Let Name(Value As String) 
    pName = Value 
End Property
```

Then you can have a collection and add instances of each class module row to it:

```
Dim ExcelRows As Collection 
Dim Row As ExcelRow

Set ExcelRows = New Collection 

Set Row = New ExcelRow
Row.Name = "Joe"
Row.HourseWorked = 3 

ExcelRows.Add Row


Set Row = New ExcelRow
Row.Name = "Sam"
Row.HourseWorked = 54 

ExcelRows.Add Row

'Or you could use a For Loop for this
```

Comment: OP should read up on dictionaries as well. Collections and dicts have different, non-overlapping uses.

Comment: This is an awesome solution! My question is now this though: if each class has a startTime and finishTime, how can I have many startTimes and finishTimes for multiple dates?

Comment: In the class module use Arrays or collections of date instead of just date

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a unique identifier, consider using that on as the key for the collection item for easy access to the data rows later on. Ash's last line of code would change to:

```
ExcelRows.Add Row, Row.Name 'given that Name is unique across the table rows
```

Later you can access the data with:

```
x = ExcelRows("Joe").HourseWorked  '= 3
```